PYSAT How to apply Clausify on Equals object when using Equals Object on a CNF?
I am using PySat library.
I need to show a cardinality constraint has the same truth value as another literal.
Here is my code,
from pysat.card import CardEnc, ITotalizer
from pysat.formula import *

cnf2 = ITotalizer(lits=[1,2,3], ubound=1, top_id=100).cnf
print(cnf2.clauses)
y = Atom(4)
cnf3 = Equals(cnf2, y)
cnf3.clausify()
print(cnf3.clauses)

Output:

[[-2, 101], [-1, 101], [-1, -2, 102], [-101, 103], [-102, 104], [-3, 103], [-3, -101, 104]]


[[-12, 4], [12, -4]]

But the Equals constraint completely ignores all the clauses defined in the original CNF and randomly adds a new literal named -12 and is using that. I don't know how to fix this issue.

This question is similar to: PySAT convert a logical formula into a CNF without using Tseitin transformation. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I absolutely don't understand how both of them are similar. My question is focused on how to apply an equals clause between a CNF and an Literal. I don't understand how that questions answer solves it. If you know how can you please point it out ?

Don't use ".clauses". Instead iterate on the cnf: for c in cnf3: print(c). You'll see a different (and hopefully more useful) result.
